# Primefaces 5 datascroller - Setting scrollHeight with Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsf, primefaces

I am using Primefaces 5 and have a LazyLoaded data scroller set as follows

```
<p:dataScroller value="#{controller.dataModel}" var="item" chunkSize="10" lazy="true" mode="inline" scrollHeight="100" id="scroller">
</p:dataScroller>
```

I want the dataScroller scrollHeight to be set to take up the full height of the space on the page which I can get via JavaScript and not a fixed size of 100.

I have bound the window resize method to recalculate the size and set it and this works, but I can't set it initially.

The javascript to set it looks like this

```
$("#scroller > div").css("height", $("#main").height());
```

And I call this after the component using

```
<h:outputScript>
    $("#scroller > div").css("height", $("#main").height());
</h:outputScript>
```

As stated, this works if I resize the window but not when the component is initially rendered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things coud be wrong. Having `id="scroller"` will not render the component with id="scroller" rather it will prepend a component id e.g. `id="form:scroller"` or a something generic like `id="j_idt19:scroller"`. So it could be that your selector is not good. However, if it gets applied on resize, it could be that you match the component well, in this case your issue is likely caused by component being loaded but not ready still. Either way, following should fix it

```
        <h:outputScript>
            $(function() {$(".ui-datascroller-content").css("height", "200px");});
        </h:outputScript>
```

You can change your selector if you're sure that that's not the issue

Comment: Great, thanks - it was not having the component ready before the javascript was executed.  This works perfectly :)